# Autocorrect mis-spelling in Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office

Until Office 2010, if I mis-spelled a word, I could right-click, choose the auo-correct option and choose a spelling which would automatically replace the mis-spelling in future.

This seems to have disappeared in Office 2103. I am hoping that it is just disabled by default.

Can I reactivate this feature somehow in Office 2013?

[Update] I am still having this problem with Office 2016, and (re)installing the Office proofing tools did not help.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. You should install Office 2013 Proofing Tools. Seems you are missing them. Of course the language of the document has to be matched.

Comment: Are you saying that you can see that option?

Comment: Yes. I have Proofing tools installed (English, German, Croatian) - I match the document or text to the language and proofing tools will autocorrect or  right click and give me optional words. check your proofing tool settings.

Here an example: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7eax5kRPs_eQmpLWVlYdEdydWs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: OK. I will check it. I have the same problem both in the office & at home, so am no too hopeful, but I will try anything :-)  I am suffering from Norovirus at the moment, but will get back as soon as I can

Comment: Alas, that does not work for me. Even after the proofing tools are installed, I see the list of possible corrections for a misspelling, but not the old menu option to add this to auto-correct for the future. Could you post a screenshot of this?